# Blocking TPL Dataflow processing

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, dataflow

I am subscribed to a real-time data feed and am maintaining a state based on the received data. Normally, all data is received in order, but in the case where a message is dropped, I buffer the messages, receive a snapshot of the state through a REST API, and then play back the buffer, skipping any messages with an Id preceding the one specified in the snapshot. Currently, I am doing the following:

```
class StateManager
{
  private long _lastId;
  private bool _isSyncing;
  private object _syncLock;

  private Dictionary<decimal,decimal> _state;  
  private ConcurrentQueue<SocketMessage> _messageBuffer;

  private ManualResetEvent _messageEvent;
  private ManualResetEvent _processingEvent;

  public StateManager( DataSocket socket )
  {
    _isSyncing = false;
    _syncLock = new object();

    _state = new Dictionary<decimal,decimal>();
    _messageBuffer = new ConcurrentQueue<SocketMessage>();

    socket.OnMessage += OnSocketMessage;
    Task.Factory.StartNew( MessageProcessingThread, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning );
  }

  public void ApplySnapshot( Snapshot snapshot )
  {
    lock( _syncLock )
    {
      if( _isSyncing ) return;

      _isSyncing = true;
      _processingEvent.Reset();
    }

    // Apply the snapshot to the state...

    _isSyncing = false;
    _processingEvent.Set();
  }

  private void OnSocketMessage( object sender, SocketMessage msg )
  {
    _messageBuffer.Enqueue( msg );
    _messageEvent.Set();
  }

  private async Task MessageProcessingThread()
  {
    while(true)
    {
      _messageEvent.WaitOne();
      while(true)
      {
        _processingEvent.WaitOne();
        if( !_messageBuffer.TryDequeue( out var msg ) )
        {
          _messageEvent.Reset();
          break;
        }
        ApplyToState( msg );
      }

    }
  }
}
```

This works fine, but I feel like it's a bit sloppy and could perform better when under heavy loads. Thus, I am looking at transitioning to `Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow`, which will handle the queueing and processing execution for me. However, I have used Dataflow before, and I have a concern:

**Is there a way I can pause the execution of an `ActionBlock` such that it will buffer new tasks but not process them until I resume?** In the case where I detect a dropped message, I need to be able to pause the processing until a fresh snapshot is applied, and then resume and process all of the buffered messages.

I could just use `_processingEvent` inside of the `ActionBlock`, but I feel like this would cause a bunch of problems. First, it would block the task, causing more tasks to be started, and those would block, quickly filling up TPL's internal task queue. Additionally, it would cause all of the blocked tasks to complete simultaneously, possibly out of order, causing another re-sync event to occur.

If this is not possible with TPL, is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: I would go with tasks. Wrap the queue with async GetItem method that MessageProcessing can await and control when it returns, ex through TaskCompletionSource. Then, once you to the point that you have to refresh the state, just don't return the messages. Apply new state, discard old messages and start returning the new ones. async/await is pretty good with performance and much easier to wrap your head around it. Also, remember to add cancellation for greacefull shutdown